# SimpleJWT returns different access and refresh token each time

Tags: django, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

So, I have a django project, and have added JWT authentication. The problem is that each time I use `TokenObtainPairView` with the same credentials I get different access and refresh tokens. Is this the default behavior, as I have not changed anything in the settings? Is there a way to get the previous token unless it has expired?

If you need more info please let me know.

Comment: Yes, that's how it works. There's a changing element to tokens.

Comment: @deceze can I get the old token unless it has expired, though?

Comment: No. Tokens aren't stored anywhere. That's the point of JWTs. You get an *equivalent* token, not *the same.*

Comment: @deceze Alright, that answers my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JWTs aren't stored anywhere, that's the entire point of them. So you can never get "the" token again. You will get an equivalent, newly generated token. Since tokens incorporate timestamps/random ids etc, you probably won't ever get the *same* token twice.

Comment: If tokens are not reproducible, how are we able to blacklist old ones when generating a new token?

Comment: Well, you *can* blacklist specific tokens. If you see that specific token and it's on your blacklist, you reject it. You'd do that if you know that a specific token has fallen into the wrong hands. That's more of a thing for very long-lived tokens, not tokens which expire every few hours anyway.

Comment: Ok, but in order to add them to a blacklist, you have to reproduce/fetch them, right?

Comment: You'd probably get them from an access log file or such. That mechanism is indeed unspecified and left up to you.

Comment: But I guess that storing the tokens to a log file defies the purpose of using JWT, right?

Comment: Well, no, the point of JWTs is that they're self-contained and contain all the information needed to identify a user, **without needing to internally query a database or centralised session storage**. Which means you can scale your server side a lot better, if you don't have the bottleneck of some centralised session storage. It also allows you to decouple your authentication service from your actual web server, which can also be interesting.

Comment: Having said that, a centralised blacklist of course kinda re-imposes this bottleneck, which might make you question the entire point of JWT all over again. Indeed, if you do use a blacklist, you should have a mechanism how the blacklist can be rolled out to your servers, instead of the server having to poll some centralised storage. This may mean that a blacklisted token may not be _immediately_ rejected by all servers, if the replication of the blacklist takes a little while.